# W3C markup validation errors

Tags: html, w3c-validation, noscript

I tried [W3C Markup validation](http://validator.w3.org/) with a simple HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="script/myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="style/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"></link> 
     <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link href="style/themeIE8.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <![endif]-->     
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript in your browser to view this page properly, to view the basic page of the site click the link <a href="no-javascipt/main.aspx">main.aspx</a>
   </noscript>

</head>
<body class="layout">
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and got the following errors

[image]

I guess in the `noscript` tag (or generally in the head tag itself) using DOM elements like `a` is not okay, Is there any alternative to that? i.e. if script is not found provide a link to a page that doesn't need script

and any idea as to why I am getting the errors for `link` & `body` tags? Thanks

Comment: `link` is self close tag. You don't need `</link>`.

Comment: @hallaji, yea didnt notice that, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`link` tag doesn't have a close tag, <s>`</link>`</s>.  As such, it's invalid.  If you want to close it inline, do it like this:

```
<link ... />
```

Also, you need to shift your `<noscript>` tag inside the `body` tag and between the `head` tag as it contains text content.

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element)

[Sitepoint Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/noscript)

---

Though, using something like this is valid if you place in the `head` tag <sup>1</sup>.

```
<noscript><link href="style/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" /></noscript>
```

> <sup>1.</sup> *In a head element, if scripting is disabled for the `noscript` element* 
>      The `noscript` element must contain only `link`, `style`, and `meta` elements.
>
> *In a head element, if scripting is enabled for the `noscript` element* 
>  
>   The `noscript` element must contain only text, except
>   that invoking the HTML fragment parsing algorithm with the noscript
>   element as the context element and the text contents as the input must
>   result in a list of nodes that consists only of `link`, `style`, and `meta`
>   elements that would be conforming if they were children of the
>   `noscript` element, and no parse errors.

Correct Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="script/myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="style/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link href="style/themeIE8.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <![endif]-->     
</head>
<body class="layout">
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript in your browser to view this page properly, to view the basic page of the site click the link <a href="no-javascript/main.aspx">main.aspx</a>
   </noscript>
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `</link>` from `if lte IE 8` too.

Comment: I treated noscript like script and didn't even thought of putting it outside the head for good practice :) , Thanks!

Comment: @rps well it's not about good practice, it's above invalid and valid \ you can refer the docs.. and you welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Check you style link which is not right. Style link should be self close. i.e.

```
<link href=".."  rel="stylesheet" />
```

and because there is written text not linked style or script so it should be under body tag.